# Can I use custom timestamps for the start and end time of a Prometheus histogram in Node.JS through Prom-Client package?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Is it possible to have a Prometheus histogram that uses custom timestamps as the start and/or end time? For example, would like to use a timestamp from the client request as the start time and then finish the time with the histogram at a specific point in the server-side code.

I am using the Node.JS [prom-client](https://github.com/siimon/prom-client)  package.
So far there does not seem to be a way to solve this with using a Histogram though.
Would still like to get the buckets workflow for viewing these times if possible.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what are you trying to accomplish? Is it an attempt to instrument some custom code to expose metrics in desired way? And if so, why aren't usual histograms in combination with function `increase` suitable for you?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.